# User Control and List<Class>

Tags: c#, winforms, list, user-controls

i am trying to use Property Editor for my user control but it doesn't work.

if i set the property in the form load if works, but if i want to use the property editor it don't save my changes (when i click again in the property editor it comes clear)

this is how i define the property in my user control:

```
private List<Field> _searchField;

public List<Field> SearchField
{
    get { return _searchField ?? (_searchField = new List<Field>()); }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply [DesignerSerializationVisibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute to  your property with `DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content`.

This tells the code generator to produces code for the contents of the object, rather than for the object itself. It helps in code generation for types other than primitive types.

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public List<int> SearchField { get { return _searchField ?? (_searchField = new List<int>()); } }
```